# How to get the Android logs remotely?

Tags: android, logging, google-analytics

Because Google told me to, I've been using Log.I , Log.E etc commands throughout my code during development.

This of course has been quite helpful during testing and debugging.

However an application that I have deployed seems to be crashing sometimes, something which I cannot replicate.

Is there a way to retrieve the logs created through the aforementioned commands from the device? I've been through the whole google development site, but there seems to be nothing on the subject (or I am missing something)

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look at [ACRA](http://www.acra.ch/) and [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/summary), this tools should help you.